# Call model method from different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model

I have a model method

```
def full_name_find(user_id)
   user = User.find(user_id)
   "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
end
```

that is in the `User` model. I would like to call it from another view (tickets#show) and I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried:

```
<%= User.full_name_find(comment.user_id) %>
```

where comment has a user_id. I get `undefined method 'full_name_find' for #<Class:0x007fd188e41108>`. I only can get it to work when I stick the `full_name_find` method into the applications helper and call in view as:

```
<%= full_name_find(comment.user_id) %>
```

and it works. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make it work by making it a class method, i.e. by putting `self.` before its name:

```
def self.full_name_find(user_id)
   user = find(user_id)
   "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
end

User.full_name_find(123)
# => "Jane Doe"
```

...but that's pretty weird. It doesn't make sense to be doing a database operation (`User.find`) in a method that's just supposed to return a user's name. A much more idiomatic approach would be a simple instance method, which will enable you to get the full name for any User instance:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Then, in your view:

```
<%= comment.user.full_name %>
```

This is much better for the reason above (not to mention being a lot simpler), but also because when you load your Comments you can use `includes` to eager-load the associated Users (e.g. `Comment.where(...).includes(:user)`), so you don't have to do a whole bunch of additional database requests to get the users' names.

Comment: Yes but I am trying to avoid writing it on every single view that I will be using a 'full name' for. Where would I go about writing these methods.

Comment: Avoid writing what? `comment.user.full_name`?